# How can I remove year from my date with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, date-formatting

I am using MomentJS to display a date.

```
moment(startDate).format('lll')
```

This will display: Jan 29 2014 03:04

But I would like to remove the year which is "2014" how can I do that?

Here is the link to the momentjs

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used that library before, but try this:

```
moment(StartDate, "MMM DD HH:mm");
```

At least this would work in .NET.

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that the OP was using 'lll' which is locale-aware. The above answer is not.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
moment(startdate).format('MMM DD h:mm A');
```

See a javascript example:

http://jsfiddle.net/remus/rLjQx/

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me (ES2022 in Angular 17) -

```
// set locale
moment.locale(locale); // where locale is any valid supported string e.g. 'en', 'es', 'pt', 'fr', etc.

//check that not past year
const now = moment(new Date().toJSON());
const blogDate = moment(v.date); // where v.date is your UTC date input e.g. '2024-02-01T13:36:47.615Z'
const pastYear = now.year() > blogDate.year();
const differenceDays = now.diff(blogDate, 'days');

const date =
differenceDays > 7
? blogDate.format(pastYear ? 'll' : 'MMM DD')
: blogDate.startOf('day').fromNow();
console.log('date', date);
```

See it live here - https://gaurav.web-developer.in/en/blog